# \Program files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.102\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(327,5): error MSB4024

Tags: c#

I am running a C# guided project but my machine cannot get past the error message posted above, lately

Dotnet build/run but the error message keeps coming up with no indication of how to resolve it. The message is quite long and pasting it to Google says "your files cannot be accessed."

Comment: The quite long message might contain information identifying the problem. Without that you can't help yourself and we can't help you. [MSB4024](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb4024?view=vs-2022)